# R function not no output after successful execution

Tags: r, function

I wrote a R function on how to calculate missing percent within a dataset, it is successfully executed but when i applied the function to my dataset, no output, no error message. I individually executed each line of my code in the function by replacing `df` with `disease`, it ran well. what is going on?

```
> Missingss <- function(df){
+     len <- length(colnames(df))
+     n <- nrow(df)
+     name <- colnames(df)
+ 
+     for (i in 1:len) {
+         if (length(subset(is.na(df[,i]), is.na(df[,i]) == 1 )) == 0)
+             sprintf ('no missing for variable %s', name[i])
+             
+         else 
+             sprintf ('missing in %s, rate %1.2f', name[i], length(subset(is.na(df[,i]), is.na(df[,i]) == 1 ))/n)
+     }
+ }
> Missingss(disease)
>
```

sneak peak of the dataset

```
> head(disease)
  Year Gender   Age Disease Cases_in_1000s
1 1990    All  0-17  Asthma            182
2 1990    All 18-24  Asthma             23
```

Comment: Is this some form of `colMeans(is.na(disease))`

Comment: I think `subset(is.na(df[,i]), is.na(df[,i]) == 1 )` is a somehow wrong usage of `subset`

Comment: @akrun Cool stuff, will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` only returns a string. You can `cat` this string if you want to output it. NB that `cat` doesn't produce newlines, so you may want to adjust your format string to include a `\n`.

```
Missingss <- function(df){
   len <- length(colnames(df))
   n <- nrow(df)
   name <- colnames(df)

   for (i in 1:len) {
     nna <- length(which(is.na(df[,i])))
     if (nna == 0)
       cat(sprintf('No missing for variable %s\n', name[i]))
     else 
       cat(sprintf('Missing in %s, rate %1.2f\n', name[i], nna/n))
   }
}
```

Another note on counting the `NA`s: You can use `length(which(is.na(df[,i])))` instead, wich is a little better in terms of readability.

```
> test <- iris
> test$Sepal.Length[42] <- NA
> test$Species[1:50] <- NA
> test$Sepal.Width <- NA
> Missingss(test)
Missing in Sepal.Length, rate 0.01
Missing in Sepal.Width, rate 1.00
No missing for variable Petal.Length
No missing for variable Petal.Width
Missing in Species, rate 0.33
>
```

Comment: You can use `print` instead of `cat` if you don't want to worry about line breaks.

Comment: @alistaire Yes, it will however add a `[1]` in front of every line, wich is why I prefer `cat`.